# Trying to get property of non-object (PHP CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

My code just for save the data session.

This is my code:

```
$idfb = 12121983918 // just sample id.

$sql = $this->db->query('SELECT * from user WHERE facebookid = "'.$idfb.'" LIMIT 1');
$datalogin = $sql->row();
$loginsession= array(

    'jenis_user' =>$datalogin->jenis_user, // the problem is here, i got eror in here, the errors is Trying to get property of non-object .
    'photo'=>$datalogin->photo,
    'facebookid'=>$datalogin->facebookid, 
    'id'=>$datalogin->id, 
    'email'=>$datalogin->email, 
    'username'=>$datalogin->username, 
    'nama'=>$datalogin->nama,
    // 'jenis_user'=>$datalogin->jenis_user,
    'alamat'=>$datalogin->alamat,
    'no_telpon'=>$datalogin->no_telpon,
);

$this->session->set_userdata('loginsession',$loginsession);

redirect($this->agent->referrer());
```

I hope someone can solved this problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: What error are you gettin'?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object.. (in my commend code )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: `$idfb = 12121983918` you did close that off, *right?* as in `$idfb = 12121983918;`

Comment: `$sql->row()` that doesn't look right. Not part of any php core mysql functions. Question's unclear, IMHO. RTM https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html seeing you're using CI.

Comment: this is from codeigniter sir.
I can use this code in my xampp, but when i use in cpanel, i got errors like that.

Comment: *"but when i use in cpanel, i got errors like that"* - Why would you run this in cpanel? that won't run, doubt it.

Comment: i just try in cpanel cause in my localhost that's work.
can you solved this one?

Comment: which version of CI you are using ? and Is other things working fine ?

Comment: I use CI 3.1.3. Please help me sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are going right

Please double check your sql, make sure that you are using right table and column names.

and try replacing

```
$sql = $this->db->query('SELECT * from user WHERE facebookid = "'.$idfb.'" LIMIT 1');
```

with

```
<?php
$this->db->where('facebookid', $idfb);
$this->db->limit(1);
$sql = $this->db->get_where('user');
?>
```

if same error, try `echo $sql->num_rows()` to see if you are getting row or not.

Comment: solved, thanks.. but i can't rate you sorry.. im beginer stack overflower...
thanks sir..

Answer (score 0):

Since database structure is not given, I can assume the database query is returning 0 rows. Always try to handle exception.

```
$idfb = 12121983918; // just sample id.

 $sql = $this->db->query('SELECT * from user WHERE facebookid = "'.$idfb.'" LIMIT 1');
 if($sql->num_rows()>0){
        $datalogin = $sql->row();
        $loginsession= array(

            'jenis_user' =>$datalogin->jenis_user, // the problem is here, i got eror in here, the errors is Trying to get property of non-object .
            'photo'=>$datalogin->photo,
            'facebookid'=>$datalogin->facebookid, 
            'id'=>$datalogin->id, 
            'email'=>$datalogin->email, 
            'username'=>$datalogin->username, 
            'nama'=>$datalogin->nama,
            // 'jenis_user'=>$datalogin->jenis_user,
            'alamat'=>$datalogin->alamat,
            'no_telpon'=>$datalogin->no_telpon,
            );

        $this->session->set_userdata('loginsession',$loginsession);

        redirect($this->agent->referrer());
  }
  else
  {
        Your Code
  }
```